# Search API in CKAN using a specific field

Tags: ckan

I want to use CKAN API to select a specific dataset using a specific field in my schema. The package search API does not work on specific dataset. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search on any default field using the `q=<field_name>:<term>` syntax, eg:

https://demo.ckan.org/api/action/package_search?q=name:sample*

https://demo.ckan.org/api/action/package_search?q=version:1.0

This can also be applied to custom fields added with [ckanext-scheming](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-scheming), eg:

https://open.canada.ca/data/api/action/package_search?q=jurisdiction:federal

If you actually want to select just one dataset and you know its id or name you can use `package_show`:

https://demo.ckan.org/api/action/package_show?id=sample-dataset-1

https://demo.ckan.org/api/action/package_show?id=c322307a-b871-44fe-a602-32ee8437ff04

Comment: Thanks @Amercader. This worked for values that do not have blank space(s). How can I search with values that contain spaces.